# How can I check the size of a particular database in TDengine?

Tags: sql, database, tdengine

I'm using TDengine database. I have several databases.

How can I check the size of a particular database?

For example, we can execute a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name",
    ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"
```

FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY table_schema;

What can I do in TDengine database ? I checked the documents, but didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, now there is no such command.

Maybe you can try

```
 show DB_NAME.vgroups;
```

find the vnodes belonging to this database. Then check the size of these vodes on disk through path `$dataDir/vnode`.